# python github clean up

Tags: python-3.x, github-api, pull-request

I am working on a python script to close a pull request, but I can't seem to format the request properly... Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
 print (repo.full_name)
 json_pulls = requests.get(base_url + repo.full_name + '/pulls?state=open+updated>=' + str(cutoff_date.date())+ '&sort=created&order=asc')
 if (json_pulls.ok):
     for item in json_pulls.json():
         print('Name: ' + item['title'])
         print('Number: ' + str(item['number']))
         print('State: ' +  item['state'])
         print('Last Updated: ' + str(item['updated_at']))
         print('Last Merged : ' + str(item['merged_at']))
         print (' ')
         pull_num = str(item['number'])
         merged_date = item['merged_at']
         if isinstance(merged_date, datetime) and (merged_date < cutoff_date):
             print('Pull Request recently merged.... Skipping... ')
             print(' ')
             print(' ')
         else:
            print('Action: Close pull request: ' + pull_num)
            print(' ')
            print(' ')
            head = {"Authorization": "Token token=" + OAUTH_KEY}
            payload = {
                "state": "closed"
            }
            r = requests.patch(base_url + repo.full_name + '/pulls/' + pull_num, head, json=payload)
            print(r.json())
```

The output:

```
Name: Issue01
Number: 1
State: open
Last Updated: 2017-04-18T14:21:31Z
Last Merged : None

Action: Close pull request: 1


{'message': 'Not Found', 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request'}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `Authorization` string is incorrect—it should be:

```
head = {"Authorization": "token " + OAUTH_KEY}
```

(From [the API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-in-a-header))